# Constructor injection of route parameter

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I have a class which I am injecting into a controller along with a route parameter. I am then using a setter to set the route parameter in the class.

routes

```
Route::get('path/of/url/with/{paramVar}', 'testController@testFunc)
```

controller

```
class testController
{
    public function testFunc(MyClassInterface $class, $routeParamVar)
    {
        $class->setParam($routeParamVar);
        //do stuff here
        ...
```

service provider

```
public function register()
{
    $this->bind('path\to\interface', 'path\to\concrete');
}
```

I would instead like to inject the route parameter into the constructor of the class I am injecting into my controller. I know [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29767443/817379) that I need to use the laravel container.

I can inject other route parameters using `Request::class`, but how can I inject the route path parameter?

I guess I would end up with something like this

```
class testController
{
    public function testFunc(MyClassInterface $class)
    {
        //do stuff here
        ...
```

Comment: Can you give some example? Or show the full testController code?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$router->input('foo')` function to retrieve a route parameter within your service container.

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_input

So in your service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->bind('path\to\interface', function(){

        $param = $this->app->make('router')->input('foo');

        return new path\to\concrete($param);

    });
}
```

In regards to your comment, it wouldn't reduce the code much, but it might be best in that case to make a second service provider, something like `FooValueServiceProvider` who's implementation's only job is to retrieve that parameter from the router.  Then in each of the bindings you could resolve a `FooValueServiceProvider` and retrieve the value from that.  Then later if you change the name of the route param, or need to resolve it from somewhere other than the route, you only need to change out the implementation of that provider.

I don't know if you can get much more efficient than just the one extra line of code per binding, but at least this way it can be changed out for a different method down the line.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this works perfectly. Have you any suggestions on how to reduce the amount of code when there are loads of binds taking this single parameter? (but returning different concretes)

Comment: I assume that if you go down this route, you have to manually inject the rest of your dependencies (since the container will no longer resolve them automatically?)

Comment: @myol hmm I don't know what you mean.  You always have to manually make dependencies with `$app->make()` in a service provider, but anywhere else (controller, model, etc) you would be able to type-hint the interface and receive the concrete class constructed with the `$param`.

Comment: I should have clarified - If a class has 3 dependencies that are auto resolved by the container, when you explicitly inject a fourth dependency, it seems you then must also explicitly inject the remaining dependencies. Is this correct or is there a way the container can still resolve the remaining dependencies automatically?

Comment: can you provide a link or example of what you mean by automatically resolved dependencies versus manually injected ones?